# Upload pictures to Picasa Web Albums directly from Gmail

Tags: gmail, picasa-web-albums

I have roughly 5G of photos in Gmail that I wish to upload to Picasa Web Albums without prior downloading. I have already checked the GData API and could not find anything that would allow me to do it, that means I would have to download 5GB first on my computer and then upload it to Picasa Web. It's a terrible waste of bandwidth.

As this is dictated only by a private need I am not desperate to write my own app, although I doubt such an application exists as I have spent a considerable amount of time on looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

> Use email upload to upload photos to Picasa Web Albums by sending them to a secret email address, especially useful from your mobile device. This allows you to stream and caption photos on-the-go. To get started, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to your acount at http://picasaweb.google.com/.
> 2. Click the gear [image] icon in the top-right corner and choose **Photos settings**.
> 3. On the **General** tab, in the "Upload photos by email" section, select the "Allow me to upload photos by email." checkbox.
> 4. Enter a "secret word," 6-15 characters long. As you enter this word, an email address appears.
> 5. Click the **Save changes** button.
> 6. To email upload your photos, just attach them to an email message and send it to the newly-created address.
>
> Use the email "Subject" line to add captions or to include the photos in a specific album. If the email "Subject" line matches an existing online album title, your photos will be uploaded to that album. Otherwise the 'Subject' line will instead be added as a caption and the photos will be placed in the Drop Box album. Learn more about [the Drop Box album](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=73970).

[Source](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83342).

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind coding a bit, you can do this with https://github.com/contextio/Gallery (you need to get an API key from [here](http://context.io/#signup)).

I never tried the Picasa API, but there seems to be one: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Showzey](http://www.showzey.com).

You can index all the photos you have in your gmail account (at first, it won't copy your photos). You can then copy the photos to picasa (or to another service).

I didn't try to batch copy *all* the pics though.